# Configuring Theano so that it doesn't directly crash when a GPU memory allocation fails

Tags: gpu, theano

When a Theano script tries to obtain more GPU memory than  currently available, it immediately crashes:

```
Error allocating 26,214,400 bytes of device memory (out of memory). 
Driver report 19,365,888 bytes free and 1,073,414,144 bytes total
```

Is there any way to configure Theano so that it doesn't directly crash when a GPU memory allocation fails? E.g., it could instead retry every X seconds, and give up after Y tries.

(One use case: I have several Theano scripts running on the same GPU and using 90% of its memory only 5% of the time)