# how to decide test batch size to fully utilise NVIDIA Titan X

Tags: deep-learning, nvidia, nvidia-titan

When training deep learning model, I found that GPU is not fully utilise if I set the train and validate(test) batch size to be same, say 32, 64, ..., 512.

Then I check NVIDIA Titan X specifications:

1. NVIDIA CUDA® Cores: 3584
2. Memory: 12 GB GDDR5X

In order to reduce test time for CNN model, I want to increase the number of samples in a batch as large as possible. I tried:

- set number of samples per batch to 3584, cuda out of memrory error.
- set number of samples per batch to 2048, cuda out of memrory error.
- set number of samples per batch to 1024, works. but I am not sure whether GPU is fully utilised or not.

Question:

How to easily pick the number of samples per batch to fully utilize GPU on deep model forward operation?

Answer (score 3):

Use `watch nvidia-smi` to check how much GPU memory your processes are using.

FYI:

- [Configuring Theano so that it doesn't directly crash when a GPU memory allocation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38724733/395857)
- [Tradeoff batch size vs. number of iterations to train a neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164876/12359):

> From Nitish Shirish Keskar, Dheevatsa Mudigere, Jorge Nocedal, Mikhail
>   Smelyanskiy, Ping Tak Peter Tang. On Large-Batch Training for Deep
>   Learning: Generalization Gap and Sharp Minima.
>   https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04836 :
>
> > The stochastic gradient descent method and its variants are algorithms of choice for many Deep Learning tasks. These methods
> >     operate in a small-batch regime wherein a fraction of the training
> >     data, usually 32--512 data points, is sampled to compute an
> >     approximation to the gradient. **It has been observed in practice that
> >     when using a larger batch there is a significant degradation in the
> >     quality of the model, as measured by its ability to generalize.**
> >     There have been some attempts to investigate the cause for this
> >     generalization drop in the large-batch regime, however the precise
> >     answer for this phenomenon is, hitherto unknown. In this paper, we
> >     present ample numerical evidence that supports the view that
> >     large-batch methods tend to converge to sharp minimizers of the
> >     training and testing functions -- and that sharp minima lead to poorer
> >     generalization. In contrast, small-batch methods consistently converge
> >     to flat minimizers, and our experiments support a commonly held view
> >     that this is due to the inherent noise in the gradient estimation. We
> >     also discuss several empirical strategies that help large-batch
> >     methods eliminate the generalization gap and conclude with a set of
> >     future research ideas and open questions.
> >
> > […]
> >
> > **The lack of generalization ability is due to the fact that large-batch methods tend to converge to *sharp minimizers* of the
> >     training function**.  These minimizers are characterized by large
> >     positive eigenvalues in $\nabla^2 f(x)$  and tend to generalize less
> >     well. In contrast, small-batch methods converge to flat minimizers
> >     characterized by small positive eigenvalues of $\nabla^2 f(x)$. We
> >     have observed that the loss function landscape of deep neural networks
> >     is such that large-batch methods are almost invariably attracted to
> >     regions with sharp minima and that, unlike small batch methods, are
> >     unable to escape basins of these minimizers.
> >
> > […]
> >
> > [image]

Comment: I am also using theano, what is your solution to "Configuring Theano so that it doesn't directly crash when a GPU memory allocation fails"

Comment: @user2262504 no solution yet.